# Include file conditionally based on a bash script

Tags: bash, puppet

I have a bash command that will return either 1 or 0. I want to run said command from puppet:

```
exec { 'Check if Thinkpad':
  command     => 'sudo dmidecode | grep -q ThinkPad && echo 1 || echo 0',
  path        => '/usr/bin/:/bin/bash/',
  environment => "HOME=/root"
}
```

Is there a way I can include a file using puppet only if my command returned 1?

```
file { '/etc/i3/config':
  source => 'puppet:///modules/i3/thinkpad',
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
  mode   => '0644',
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an external fact to use the bash script as is. Inside the module's `facts.d` directory, you could place the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ dmidecode | grep -q ThinkPad ]
  echo 'is_thinkpad=true'
else
  echo 'is_thinkpad=false'
fi
```

You can also use a custom fact inside the `lib/facter` directory of your module.

```
Facter.add(:is_thinkpad) do
  confine kernel: linux
  setcode do 
    `dmidecode | grep -q ThinkPad && echo true || echo false`
  end
end
```

In both cases, the fact name of `is_thinkpad` follows the convention for the nomenclature of boolean facts for types of systems. You can then update the code in your manifest for this boolean.

```
if $facts['is_thinkpad'] == true {
  file { '/etc/i3/config':
    source => 'puppet:///modules/i3/thinkpad',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0644',
  }
}
```

This will provide you with the functionality you desire.

https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html#adding-custom-facts-to-facter
https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html#external-facts

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to turn your bash script into a "custom fact" -- which is something I've only done once and don't fully understand enough to teach you how.

I want to say that the easiest way to set up a custom fact is to put your script into `/etc/facter/facts.d/` on the **agent** machine, and make sure it ends with a line that says

```
echo "thinkpadcheck=1"
```

or

```
echo "thinkpadcheck=0"
```

You can test it with (note: you must be `root`)

```
sudo facter -p | grep think
```

and it should return

```
thinkpadcheck => 1
```

But once you have done that, then your puppet script can say

```
if $thinkpadcheck == 1
{
  file { '/etc/i3/config':
   source      => 'puppet:///modules/i3/thinkpad',
    owner       => 'root',
    group       => 'root',
    mode        => '0644',
  }
}
else
{
    notify { "thinkpadcheck failed for $hostname" : }
}
```

Comment: Corrections: this is an external fact, they should be placed in `facts.d` inside the module, the fact lookup should be `$facts['thinkpadcheck']`, and the facter lookup should be `sudo facter -p thinkpadcheck`. Also, you should add the doc to your answer: https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html#external-facts. With those fixes, this is a good answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard  I'm a little confused -- the doc that you mentioned lists `/etc/facter/facts.d/` as (one of) the place to put my facter scripts.  Why would I want to put them in the module?  For that matter, why would I want to "attach" my custom facts to only a single module?

Comment: @MattSchuchard You may be using a newer version of puppet/facter than I am, because most of your changes did not work for me.

Comment: Are you using a long-obsolete version of Puppet? You should probably also note that in your answer then and query for the version he is using.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share another method I found in the [Puppet Cookbook 3rd edition](http://download.smkn4padalarang.sch.id/Ebook/sysadm/Puppet%20Cookbook,%203rd%20Edition.pdf) (page 118):

**message.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "This runs on the master if you are centralized"
```

Make your script executable with:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/message.rb
```

**message.pp**

```
$message = generate('/usr/local/bin/message.rb')
notify { $message: }
```

Then run:

```
puppet apply message.pp
```

---

*This example uses a ruby script but any type of script including a basic shell script, as was needed in my case, can be used to set a variable in puppet.*